# How to do a static build

Tags: go, cgo

I'm building a Go app which depends on some packages that uses C code.
I would like the resulting binary of my app to be have all those dependencies statically linked.

I did manage to get almost everything related to the package's dependency static, but I have some `libc` and `libgcc`, which I believe I'm not even supposed to try to make it static.

```
✦ ldd myapp
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd921ec000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f445310a000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f44530c8000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f44530ad000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4452ec3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4453150000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4452ebd000)
```

If I try to run this binary in another machine, even if it is the same linux distro, I get the error

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by ./app)
```

This is how I'm building it

```
export CGO_CFLAGS="`pkg-config --cflags MagickWand MagickCore`"
export CGO_LDFLAGS="\
-lstdc++ -fopenmp \
-Wl,-Bstatic \
    `pkg-config --libs MagickWand MagickCore` -lpng16 -ljpeg -lz -lm -lc -lxml2 -lfreetype -lexpat \
-Wl,-Bdynamic"

go build -i -tags no_pkgconfig .
```

How can I build a usable binary when I need cgo?

Comment: can we not dockerise and run it via a docker?

Comment: I believe libgcc_s and libc are pulled in by go tool link itself as when using cgo some parts of runtime might use shared libraries instead of go implementation. Have you tried with `-tags netgo` (for host resolution) and `-tags osusergo` (for user and group resolution) to skip these? As for libc.so.6 on same (or backwards compatible libc) it should work, can you check if you have same libc on both distros?

Comment: What @blami said. Also it might worth it to first sort out a fully-static build of a simpler program with C-dependent parts deliberately left out, and then add the statically-built C deps back.

Comment: @LunaLovegood, thanks for your comment. I tried the exact same code running on a go:alpine. I get the same result but instead of the dynamic link to libc I get it to musl. Do you have a working example of a simple app compiling static libs in Docker?

Comment: Hi @blami, what is really weird for me, is that I compiled on Ubuntu 20.04, and it doesn't run on another fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04. Shouldn't libc be present from start on linux? I am not sure if only skipping net and user will do anything, because probably imagemagick is to blame here, but I will give it a shot anyway, Thanks!  I will also try what kostix suggested.